# How to align the button at the bottom with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using version Bootstrap [4.0.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Here's an example:: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/pricing/

How can I make a button always aligned to the **bottom**?

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34shLh1m/

Code **html**:

```
<div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
  <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
      <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
        <li>10 users included</li>
        <li>2 GB of storage</li>
        <li>Email support</li>
        <li>Help center access</li>
        <li>Help center access</li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
      <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
        <li>20 users included</li>
        <li>10 GB of storage</li>
        <li>Priority email support</li>
        <li>Help center access</li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Photo:**

I want to do something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Apply the classes `d-flex flex-column` to the card-body (they turn the card body into a flex column) and the class `mt-auto` (margin-top:auto) to the button. `mt-auto` pushes the button to the bottom.

Here's a working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                <li>10 users included</li>
                <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                <li>Email support</li>
                <li>Help center access</li>
                <li>Help center access</li>
                <li>Help center access</li>
                <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary mt-auto">Sign up for free</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                <li>20 users included</li>
                <li>10 GB of storage</li>
                <li>Priority email support</li>
                <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mt-auto">Get started</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to do the same thing without card layout ? can you please help me ?